Generating Solovay pointclasses
$\DeclareMathOperator{\HOD}{HOD}$
Assume $\text{AD}^+ + V=L(P(ℝ))$, and let $θ_α$ be the Solovay sequence.  Let $s⊂\mathrm{Ord}$ of order type $ω$ be cofinal in $(θ_α^+)^{\HOD}$.  Under what circumstances does $Θ^{\HOD(s,ℝ)}=θ_{α+1}$, and what kind of model is $\HOD(s,ℝ)$ otherwise?
I expect that $∀κ<Θ \, \operatorname{cf}((κ^+)^{\HOD})=ω$ because in models of $\text{AD}^+$ so far containing all the reals, HOD (albeit externally to the model) is an iterate of a countable mouse/structure, and the model is sufficiently closed below $Θ$.
Assuming mouse capturing and $\text{AD}_ℝ$ and no long extenders (and presumably unconditionally), if HOD has a Woodin cardinal $δ$ with $θ_α < δ < θ_{α+1}$, then sets of reals of Wadge rank $θ_α$ are not in $\HOD(s,ℝ)$. (See Theorem 5.3 in Mouse Pairs and Suslin Cardinals by John Steel.)  However, I do not know whether in the absence of such $δ$, for some or even all $s$, $Θ^{\HOD(s,ℝ)}=θ_{α+1}$.  Moreover, with such $δ$, $\HOD(s,ℝ)$ (for some or all $s$) appears to be a canonical model and part of a natural hierarchy of models, bringing some aspects of AD beyond $P(ℝ)$.  Understanding such models may also be important for core model induction, which already below a Woodin limit of Woodin cardinals hits a roadblock (called Sealing) that suggests going beyond $P(ℝ)$.
Some background:  A good (but slightly outdated) background relating Solovay pointclasses to inner models is in Derived models associated to mice by John Steel.  Let $M$ be an extender-based (rather than least branch) mouse $M$ projecting $ω$ and having a limit of Woodin cardinals $λ$, and such that $M$ does not lose strength from $\operatorname{Coll}(κ,ω)$ for $κ<λ$ and taking HOD; not sure if we need other conditions.  Let $N$ be the derived model at $λ$ that uses genericity iterations to make $ℝ^N=ℝ$.  At Wadge rank exactly $θ_0^N$, we have the operator $x→M(x)$ and also the iteration strategy for the least Woodin cardinal $δ$ of $M$.  $\HOD^N$ is an iterate of $M$ (or at least it should have an iterate $N|λ$) together with a fragment of the iteration strategy; the least Woodin of $\HOD^N$ is $θ_0^N$ and corresponds to $δ$ in $M$.
    If $M$ has a $<λ$-strong cardinal, then $N$ has a set of reals of Wadge rank $θ_0^N$.  In that case, let $M'$ be based on the large cardinal structure of $M$ above its least $<λ$-strong cardinal, but in the portion below the ordinal corresponding to $λ$, augmented with the closure under (operator) $M$.  Then at Wadge rank $θ_1^N$ we have $x→M'(x)$ and also the iteration strategy for the first Woodin cardinal of $M'$ (which corresponds to $θ_1^N$).  $θ_1^N$ is the second Woodin cardinal of $HOD^N$, and the first Woodin of $HOD_A^N$ where $A$ encodes $x→M(x)$ ($x∈ℝ$, which suffices to get all $x∈HOD_A^N|Θ$).  $HOD_A^N$ is based on an iterate of $M'$, analogously to $\HOD^N$.  I think $V=HOD$ fails in $M'$ (and in $HOD_A^N$), with its HOD being an iterate of $M$ together with a fragment of the iteration strategy (that, as usual, does not add bounded subsets of the image of $δ$).
    The situation at $θ_2^N$ and so on is analogous. $θ_α^N$ for nonlimit $α$ are precisely the cut-point Woodin cardinals of $HOD^N$ (assuming $V=L(P(ℝ))$ in $N$, but including some mouse structure above $P(ℝ)$ should not affect $HOD^N|Θ^N$).
Now, letting $Γ_α$ consist of all sets of reals of Wadge rank $<θ_α$, to get a set of reals of Wadge rank $θ_α$, we need to go outside $\HOD(Γ_α)$, and (externally) a natural choice appears to be a mouse above $Γ_α$ that coiterates past $\HOD(Γ_α)$ and projects to $θ_α$.  While the model cannot identify such a mouse (even if it is in the model), it might be encodable by an $ω$ sequence cofinal in $(θ_α^+)^{\HOD}$, analogously to how for every $κ≥ω_2$, $0^\#$ is constructible from every $ω$ sequence cofinal in $(κ^+)^L$.  (And $Γ_α$ should be generic over HOD by a forcing of HOD cardinality $θ_α$, so $(θ_α^+)^{\HOD} = (θ_α^+)^{\HOD(Γ_α)}$.)
For nonlimit $α$ with $θ_α<Θ$, $\operatorname{cf}(θ_α)=ω$ and there is cofinal $s⊂θ_α$ of order type $ω$ such that $\HOD(s,ℝ)$ includes a set of reals of Wadge rank $θ_α$.  For $θ_0$, every such (i.e. cofinal of order type $ω$) $s$ works, but I do not know whether this holds for successor $α$.  For cofinality $ω$ $α$ with $θ_α<Θ$, some but (at least if $\operatorname{cf}(α)^{\HOD}=ω$) not all such $s$ give a set of reals of Wadge rank $θ_α$; I do not know about $s$ cofinal in $(θ_α^+)^{\HOD}$.  For uncountable cofinality $α$, and $s$ of order type $ω$ cofinal in $(θ_α^+)^{\HOD}$, $\HOD(s,Γ_α)$ is independent of $s$, but I do not know whether $\HOD(s,ℝ)=\HOD(s,Γ_α)$.  Given the independence of $s$, we can try iterating by letting $s'$ of length $ω$ be cofinal in $(κ^+)^{\HOD(s,Γ_α)}$ for the least possible $κ$ (perhaps $κ$ is the least Woodin in HOD above $θ_α$), plausibly consuming one Woodin or limit of Woodins in HOD per iteration for countable iterations.  Adding a set of reals of rank $θ_α$ should be the last step here before adding a set of reals of rank $θ_{α+1}$.  Plausibly, under $\text{AD}^+ + V=L(P(ℝ))$, $θ_α$ is a Woodin limit of Woodin cardinals in HOD iff there is a Wadge rank $<θ_α$ set of reals outside of $∪_{β<θ_α} \, \HOD(β^ω)$ (and outside of $\HOD(\mathrm{Ord}^ω)$ if $θ_α=Θ$).

A theorem of Woodin's from last year implies that $\text{cf}(\kappa^{+\text{HOD}}) = \omega$ for all $\kappa < \Theta$ if and only if for all $\kappa < \Theta$, $\text{HOD}$ satisfies "$\kappa$ is not $\kappa^{+}$-supercompact."

@GabeGoldberg Thanks.  Can you point me to which paper it is in (or is it a privately circulated preprint)?

@GabeGoldberg To confirm, you only need $(κ^+)^{\mathrm{HOD}}$ rather than $(κ^+)^V$-supercompact in HOD, right?  Plausibly, AD$^+$ (for $\mathrm{HOD}(ℝ)$) is an anti-large-cardinal assumption, and the cardinals in its $\mathrm{HOD}^{L(P(ℝ))}$ are restricted even further, but I have no firm opinion on where/if the transition happens.

Yes, I meant letting $\delta = \kappa^{+\text{HOD}}$, $\text{HOD}$ satisfies $\kappa$ is not $\delta$-supercompact. The equivalence I mentioned is a consequence of Woodin's recent proof of his HOD ultrafilter conjecture. Another consequence is that it is an outright theorem of $\text{AD}^++V = L(P(\mathbb R))$ that no cardinal $\kappa$ is $\kappa^{+V}$-supercompact in $\text{HOD}$. The proof of the HOD ultrafilter conjecture is very similar to the proof of UA in HOD. Neither is published, but a sketch of the latter appears in my notes here: https://math.berkeley.edu/~goldberg/Slides/IIMT.pdf
